SD Card Power Supply Behavior
I am having some trouble getting an SD card to mount on my esp32 custom board. After exhausting numerous troubleshooting options I bought the ESP32-S3N32 Dev Board.
The SD card module I am using are HiLetgo micro SD card adapters that I bypassed the 5V to 3.3V regulator on.
I am using the standard ESP32-S3 Dev Module SD SPI Example in Arduino 2.3.2 using the following custom pins:
sck => 40;
miso => 39;
mosi => 41;
cs => 42;
The VCC is connected to one of the 3.3V pins on the Dev module and the Ground is connected to one of the ground pins also on the Dev Module.
When done this worked perfectly, the card mounted and created the files and then closed out. I unplugged the module then and connected VCC and GND to my power supply giving it 3.3V as measured at the SD card module with a multimeter.
When plugging back in the Dev module it is no longer able to mount the card. I then reconnected the power pins of the SD card module to the dev board and the script started to work again.
Finally I connected the power pins back to the power supply and reflashed the microcontroller and it continued to fail to mount. I varied the power supply to +/- .2V with no change in behavior. After plugging it back into the dev module again and resetting the sd card returned to normal operation.
I am really confused at what is going on here then. Why does the SD card module work when power is plugged into the dev module but not when it's connected to a power supply?
#include "FS.h"
#include "SD.h"
#include "SPI.h"



#define REASSIGN_PINS
int sck = 40;
int miso = 39;
int mosi = 41;
int cs = 42;



void listDir(fs::FS &fs, const char *dirname, uint8_t levels) {
  Serial.printf("Listing directory: %s\n", dirname);


  File root = fs.open(dirname);
  if (!root) {
    Serial.println("Failed to open directory");
    return;
  }
  if (!root.isDirectory()) {
    Serial.println("Not a directory");
    return;
  }


  File file = root.openNextFile();
  while (file) {
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
      Serial.print("  DIR : ");
      Serial.println(file.name());
      if (levels) {
        listDir(fs, file.path(), levels - 1);
      }
    } else {
      Serial.print("  FILE: ");
      Serial.print(file.name());
      Serial.print("  SIZE: ");
      Serial.println(file.size());
    }
    file = root.openNextFile();
  }
}


void createDir(fs::FS &fs, const char *path) {
  Serial.printf("Creating Dir: %s\n", path);
  if (fs.mkdir(path)) {
    Serial.println("Dir created");
  } else {
    Serial.println("mkdir failed");
  }
}


void removeDir(fs::FS &fs, const char *path) {
  Serial.printf("Removing Dir: %s\n", path);
  if (fs.rmdir(path)) {
    Serial.println("Dir removed");
  } else {
    Serial.println("rmdir failed");
  }
}


void readFile(fs::FS &fs, const char *path) {
  Serial.printf("Reading file: %s\n", path);


  File file = fs.open(path);
  if (!file) {
    Serial.println("Failed to open file for reading");
    return;
  }


  Serial.print("Read from file: ");
  while (file.available()) {
    Serial.write(file.read());
  }
  file.close();
}


void writeFile(fs::FS &fs, const char *path, const char *message) {
  Serial.printf("Writing file: %s\n", path);


  File file = fs.open(path, FILE_WRITE);
  if (!file) {
    Serial.println("Failed to open file for writing");
    return;
  }
  if (file.print(message)) {
    Serial.println("File written");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Write failed");
  }
  file.close();
}


void appendFile(fs::FS &fs, const char *path, const char *message) {
  Serial.printf("Appending to file: %s\n", path);


  File file = fs.open(path, FILE_APPEND);
  if (!file) {
    Serial.println("Failed to open file for appending");
    return;
  }
  if (file.print(message)) {
    Serial.println("Message appended");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Append failed");
  }
  file.close();
}


void renameFile(fs::FS &fs, const char *path1, const char *path2) {
  Serial.printf("Renaming file %s to %s\n", path1, path2);
  if (fs.rename(path1, path2)) {
    Serial.println("File renamed");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Rename failed");
  }
}


void deleteFile(fs::FS &fs, const char *path) {
  Serial.printf("Deleting file: %s\n", path);
  if (fs.remove(path)) {
    Serial.println("File deleted");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Delete failed");
  }
}


void testFileIO(fs::FS &fs, const char *path) {
  File file = fs.open(path);
  static uint8_t buf[512];
  size_t len = 0;
  uint32_t start = millis();
  uint32_t end = start;
  if (file) {
    len = file.size();
    size_t flen = len;
    start = millis();
    while (len) {
      size_t toRead = len;
      if (toRead > 512) {
        toRead = 512;
      }
      file.read(buf, toRead);
      len -= toRead;
    }
    end = millis() - start;
    Serial.printf("%u bytes read for %lu ms\n", flen, end);
    file.close();
  } else {
    Serial.println("Failed to open file for reading");
  }


  file = fs.open(path, FILE_WRITE);
  if (!file) {
    Serial.println("Failed to open file for writing");
    return;
  }


  size_t i;
  start = millis();
  for (i = 0; i < 2048; i++) {
    file.write(buf, 512);
  }
  end = millis() - start;
  Serial.printf("%u bytes written for %lu ms\n", 2048 * 512, end);
  file.close();
}


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial) {
    delay(10);
  }


#ifdef REASSIGN_PINS
  SPI.begin(sck, miso, mosi, cs);
  if (!SD.begin(cs)) {
#else
  if (!SD.begin()) {
#endif
    Serial.println("Card Mount Failed");
    return;
  }
  uint8_t cardType = SD.cardType();


  if (cardType == CARD_NONE) {
    Serial.println("No SD card attached");
    return;
  }


  Serial.print("SD Card Type: ");
  if (cardType == CARD_MMC) {
    Serial.println("MMC");
  } else if (cardType == CARD_SD) {
    Serial.println("SDSC");
  } else if (cardType == CARD_SDHC) {
    Serial.println("SDHC");
  } else {
    Serial.println("UNKNOWN");
  }


  uint64_t cardSize = SD.cardSize() / (1024 * 1024);
  Serial.printf("SD Card Size: %lluMB\n", cardSize);


  listDir(SD, "/", 0);
  createDir(SD, "/mydir");
  listDir(SD, "/", 0);
  removeDir(SD, "/mydir");
  listDir(SD, "/", 2);
  writeFile(SD, "/hello.txt", "Hello ");
  appendFile(SD, "/hello.txt", "World!\n");
  readFile(SD, "/hello.txt");
  deleteFile(SD, "/foo.txt");
  renameFile(SD, "/hello.txt", "/foo.txt");
  readFile(SD, "/foo.txt");
  testFileIO(SD, "/test.txt");
  Serial.printf("Total space: %lluMB\n", SD.totalBytes() / (1024 * 1024));
  Serial.printf("Used space: %lluMB\n", SD.usedBytes() / (1024 * 1024));
}


void loop() {}```


In some situations/configurations the SD card interface requires power toggling. Maybe your development board uses this function.

Thank you for your answer. Do you know how to check if the SD card is looking for this?

I don't remember details. It is a part of SD protocol. Card Reader interface is supposed to control SD power. You might want to check specifications for MMC, they are similar but open.

Why are you anyway switching the GND and VCC of the card to another supply? Did you really disconnect the card GND from ESP32 and still expect it to work?
